# How can I bring back indentation workaround in Rmarkdown pandoc genuine references?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, pandoc

I'm using RStudio's Rmarkdown with genuine pandoc citation. I also use a LaTeX coded workaround to indent the references. Until RStudio version 1.0.153 this method worked pretty well. Since the latest version 1.1.383 it is not working anymore.

This is my code:

````
---
title: Example
author: Author
output: pdf_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
# Chapter
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy 
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam 
voluptua [@hawking_thermodynamics_1983]. At Einstein [-@einstein_ist_1905] 
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea 
rebum.

# References
\vspace{-.55cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\noindent
<div id="refs"></div>
```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
# PrintBibliography(bib) 
```
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

# Appendix
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
````

The content of the bibliography.bib:

```
@article{einstein_ist_1905,
    title = {Ist die Trägheit eines Körpers von seinem Energieinhalt abhängig?},
    volume = {323},
    url = {https://s3.amazonaws.com/objects.readcube.com/articles/downloaded/wiley/a56a92baf12b80889d9de6f28f51f22f8bec1a2b366de4e8171f0d47e890d37a.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22Einstein-1905-Annalen_der_Physik.pdf%22&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIS5LBPCM5JPOCDGQ%2F20170830%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20170830T124037Z&X-Amz-Expires=127162&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=3de93a7b9a7edbcc0676232820c448641df14f4a22d339ad07a8cc06200d7632},
    doi = {doi:10.1002/andp.19053231314},
    pages = {639--641},
    journaltitle = {Ann. Phys.},
    author = {Einstein, Albert},
    urldate = {2017-08-30},
    date = {1905},
    file = {a56a92baf12b80889d9de6f28f51f22f8bec1a2b366de4e8171f0d47e890d37a.pdf:C\:\\Users\\jay\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\dbkhbdqv.default\\zotero\\storage\\TTPHSMIX\\a56a92baf12b80889d9de6f28f51f22f8bec1a2b366de4e8171f0d47e890d37a.pdf:application/pdf}
}

@article{hawking_thermodynamics_1983,
    title = {Thermodynamics of black holes in anti-de Sitter space},
    volume = {87},
    issn = {0010-3616, 1432-0916},
    url = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/BF01208266},
    doi = {10.1007/BF01208266},
    pages = {577--588},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {Communications in Mathematical Physics},
    author = {Hawking, S. W. and Page, Don N.},
    urldate = {2017-10-13},
    date = {1983-12},
    langid = {english},
    file = {57cae4b908ae3ac722b1eaa1.pdf:C\:\\Users\\jay\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\dbkhbdqv.default\\zotero\\storage\\DZ38DDCK\\57cae4b908ae3ac722b1eaa1.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

Former PDF outcome with RStudio v 1.0.153:
[image]

PDF outcome with latest RStudio v 1.1.383:
[image]

As you can see the `<div>` tag (which is used in order to let the references appear before the appendix) seems no more to be recognized. I can't figure anything out of the [RStudio Release History](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200716783-RStudio-Release-History).

Has anybody the knowledge of how I can bring back the indentations of the references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a newline before and after the `<div id="refs"></div>`:

````
...
\noindent

<div id="refs"></div>

```{r refmgr references, results="asis", echo=FALSE}
...
````

[image]

Comment: Sometimes, little things make a big difference.

Comment: Aye :-) I think this was a pandoc parser version behaviour change that likely surfaced since the pandoc that ships w/rstudio gets updated as well.